# Having problems with for loop and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, binary

(I know there is easier way to convert to binary but I didn't know that before I was almost finished with this. So I am just gonna try to finish this. I coded this just to learn) :)
I am trying to create a function that converts binary to ASCII code. Here is how I am converting from binary to number:

```
function fromBinaryToNumber(num) {
  let numbers = num.split('') //turns the binary into an array
  let firstIndexWith1;
  let numbersToAdd = [];
  let result;

  //Delete 0's at start of array
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = parseInt(numbers[i], 10);
  }
  firstIndexWith1 = numbers.indexOf(1);
  numbers.splice(0, firstIndexWith1);

  //Convert
  let checkAgainstThese = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1];
  checkAgainstThese = checkAgainstThese.slice(checkAgainstThese.length - numbers.length, checkAgainstThese.length);

  //put numbers to add in array
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] === 1) {
      numbersToAdd.push(checkAgainstThese[i]);
    }
  }

  //add numbers
  result = numbersToAdd.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return result;
}
```

It works. But I want to be able to convert more than one byte at a time. This is how I am trying to do that:

```
function fromBinaryToASCII(sentence) {
  let convertThis = sentence.split(' ');
  let result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < convertThis.length; i++) {
    result.push(fromBinaryToNumber(convertThis[i]));
  }
  return result;
}
```

I have already made a function that successfully converts from a sentence to binary and for some reason that one works but not this one, even though they both look very similar.

So I was trying to find out what the problem was and I tried putting a console.log inside the for loop and printing out the i. Like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < convertThis.length; i++) {
  result.push(fromBinaryToNumber(convertThis[i]));
  console.log(i);
}
```

And for some reason it outputted only the number 6. When I remove the result.push code it outputs correctly. I am very confused. Can someone help me?
-Thanks

(sorry for bad title or if i explained badly)

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: well I do not see you using var so have fun with global variables overriding each other. Each for loop uses `i` and you do not delcare `i` so they are the same...

Comment: any console error?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just do `var binary = "101"; var dec = parseInt(binary, 2)`?

Comment: Tibrogargan, I found I could do that some hours ago so yeah.. I am just doing this to learn

Comment: Good reason :)  You should maybe mention that in your question so you don't get this as trivial answers

Comment: It seems the whole issue could be handled in one `return sentence.split(' ').map(n => parseInt(n, 2))`

Comment: epascarello, using var seems to have fixed it. Thanks. When I was learning for loops I got told that it was no point in using var!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i<convertThis.length; i++) {  <-- global i

for(i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {  <-- global i
```

When the one runs, it will change the number for the other.... This is why `var` is not optional. So either use let or var

```
for(let i=0; i<convertThis.length; i++) { 

for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
```